# Size of the file to be uploaded (attached) in silverlight .NET

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am making an attachment component in Silverlight and was wondering if they do have an api in Silverlight .NET or a way to know the size of the file before I start uploading it.  Something like Gmail...

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `OpenFileDialog` to have the user pick the file to upload?  If so, it gives you a `FileInfo`, which has a `Length` property.  If you are not using `OpenFileDialog`, what are you using to access files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
const int megaSize = 1024000;
            if (ofd.File.Length > megaSize)
                ShowError("Can not upload images with this size.");
```

Hope it helps